# Notation for product measure of a sequence of meaures

Tags: measure-theory, notation

Suppose I have a collection of measures $\lbrace \mu_i: i \in B \rbrace$ where $B$ is finite index set. Is the following notation standard for describing the product measure?

$$
\bigotimes_{i\in{B}}\mu_i
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a standard notation for products (not only of measures).